# Two different Java applications sharing the same database

Tags: java, hibernate, integration

In my web application I have a part which needs to continuously crawl the Web, process those data and present it to a user. So I was wondering if it is a good approach to split it up into two separate applications where one would do the crawling, data processing and store the data in the database. And the other app would be a web application (mounted on some web server) which would present to a user the data from the database and allow him a certain interaction with the data.

The reason I think I need this split is because if I make certain changes to my web app (like adding new functionalities, change the interface etc.) I wouldn't like the crawling to be interrupted.

My application stack is Tapestry (web layer), Spring, Hibernate (over MySQL) and my own implementation of the crawler independent from the others.

Is it good for the integration to be done just by using the same database? This might cause an issue with accessing the database from the both applications at the same time. Or can the integration be done on the Hibernate level, so both applications could use the same Hibernate session? But can the app from one JVM instance access the object from another JVM instance?

I would be grateful for any suggestions regarding this matter.

UPDATE

The user (from web app's interface) would enter the URLs for crawler to parse. The crawler app would just read the tables with URLs the web app populates. And vice versa, the data processed by the crawler would just be presented on the user interface. So, I think I shouldn't concern about any kind locking, right?

Thanks,
Nikola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely keep them separated like you are planning. The web crawling is more a "batch" process than a request driven web application. The web crawling app will run in its own JVM and your web app will be running in a servlet/Java EE container.

How often will the crawler run or is it a continuously running process? You may want to consider the frequency based on your requirements.

Will the users from web app be updating the same tables that the crawler will post data to? In that case you will need to take precaution otherwise a potential deadlock may arise. If you want your web app to auto refresh data based on new inserts in the tables then you can create a message driven bean (using [JMS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/index.html)) to asynchronously notify the web app from the crawler app. When a new data insert message arrives you can either do a form submit on your page or use ajax to update the data on the page itself.

The web app should use connection pooling and the batch app could use [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). I am not sure you gain much benefit by trying to share the database sessions in this scenario.

This way you have the integration between the two apps while not slowing down each other waiting on other to process.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! User would insert the URLs of the pages for crawler to crawl, but the crawler app would just read that table, not updating it on any means. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, splitting the application into two could be reasonable in your case.

Disadvantages of separating into two applications -

- You can not cache in Hibernate or any other cached mutable objects that are modifiable from both applications in any one of them. Optimistic locking should work fine with two hibernate applications. I don't see any other problems.

Advantages you have already specified in your code.